# how do I make my code check for if it has special characters/symbols?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to write a program that checks the strength of a password entered by the user. So far, I want my password to check if the password contains a symbol. If the password contains a symbol, uppercase, lowercase, and a number, the password should be considered strong. Alternatively, if the password only consists of 3 of the 4 qualities in any order/combination, the password should also be strong. However, if the password only consists of two of these things, then the password is considered medium. The code mostly works, however, once I add a symbol, regardless of other combinations, the password is considered strong.

This also happens in one of my other things. what do I do?
Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def getInfo():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def passwordStrength():
    password = ''
    strength = ''
    length = ''
    specialCharacters = "!@#$%^&*()`~-_=+[{]}\|;:'<,>.?/"
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'Password':
        password = str(request.form.get('Password'))
        length = len(password)
        if length >= 18:
            strength = 'Godlike'
        elif length == 17:
            if any(i.isupper and i.islower and i.isdigit and i in specialCharacters for i in password):
                strength = 'Godlike'
            else:
                strength = 'Strong'
        elif length == 14:
            if any(i.isupper and i.islower and i.isdigit and i in specialCharacters for i in password):
                strength = 'Strong'
            elif any(not i.isupper for i in password):
                strength = 'Strong'
            elif any(not i.islower for i in password):
                strength = 'Strong'
            elif any(not i.isdigit for i in password):
                strength = 'Strong'
            elif any(not i in specialCharacters for i in password):
                strength = 'Strong'
            else:
                strength = 'Meduim'
```

When I input the password 123456789NOSYM should output medium, but it outputs strong (this is also a problem)
When I input the password NOSYMBOLSPLEAS should also output medium, but it outputs strong.
When I input the password 123456789YES!! should output medium, but it also outputs strong.

These are just a couple of examples

Comment: a first place to start looking might be the following : `isupper`, `islower` and `isdigit` are all methods, not properties, and must therefore be called to be evaluated. i.e. try changeing `i.isupper` to `i.isupper()` everywhere

Comment: Otherwise, it's generally a good idea to condense your code to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can easily run on our own machines to debug it (i.e. strip out all the Flask references, as they have no impact on your problem). 
As a bonus, doing this will probably help you find several issues in your code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

For the first and second passwords you enter, the last elif is True, which makes it strong.

For the last password, the first elif is True, which also makes it strong.

Comment: Just realised that the second example should in fact output Strong. But the first two examples should output medium

Comment: @JackPendergast First of all you need to change isdigit, isupper and islower to isdigit(), isupper() and islower().